# ANTLR 2 SBT plugin dependencies

Tags: java, sbt, antlr, typesafe-activator, antlr2

I have defined the following in the build.sbt

`libraryDependencies += "antlr" % "antlr" % "2.7.7"`

I have placed my `sample.g` file in src/main/antlr
I also have my java files in src/main/java.

I use `activator compile` to compile the files. The java files are compiled and classes are created, but the parser and lexer file generation doesn't happen for the grammar files. Do I need to set any other configuration for it to automatically generate the files?

Note that the grammar file was written sometime back. Porting to ANTLR 3/4 would require significant effort.

Comment: Grammar file was written sometime back. Porting to ANTLR 3/4 would require significant effort.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've added that to your question.